# solaris crontab の実行通知を止める方法

Tags: solaris

crontab で実行したコマンドの標準出力、標準エラー出力がcrontab 実行ユーザにメールで通知されるという初期設定になっていると思われます。

そのメールの通知を止めたいのですが、方法がわからない為お教えいただけると幸いです。

宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

標準出力、エラー出力ともに必要無ければ`/dev/null`に対してリダイレクトしてしまう方法があります。

```
0 1 * * * /path/to/command.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```